# Is it possible to compile v8 as a managed assembly?

Tags: .net, clr, mozilla, v8

The reason for this is the absence of a good quality, fast JavaScript engine on .net platform. 
Imagine that you need an ability to access many .net objects (e.g. ORM model) in a running script in such a way that a end user could customize them.

I can see a couple of options:

- to use one of the existing .net implementations. Suprisingly, there are only few feasible choices: [jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) and [ironjs](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS). Jurassic is really good, stable, supports Ecma5, but is slow compared to the native
  engines (mozilla, v8). IronJS is promising but it does not support Ecma5 officially and its development seems to have slowed down.
- to link a managed code with a native engine in a mixed application. It does work and I have done it with mozilla engine before. The problem is that if you have a lot of .net objects that should be
  visible in a script, you will have to pay big price on native/managed transition and that can compromise performance.
- to compile a native engine (v8 is a better candidate) as a managed assembly and use it directly in .net. Basically, it is a attempt to eliminate the trade-off mentioned above.

My question is if the third approach is worth trying? Has anybody tried it already?

Thanks!

Update (7/02/2012):
If anybody is interested, we have made such experiment on mozilla jseng. One of my colleagues spent lots of time trying to make it work. Finally when we reached the point where all mozilla jseng code became managed and almost none native/managed transitions presented in the code, the result was unexpected - the performance was the same. So, in out case native/managed transition was not the main issue.

Comment: Getting V8 to run under the CLR sounds like quite the undertaking.  It's for sure full of pointer arithmetic, and other "unsafe" code..

Comment: Doesn't rewriting it for .NET (which is what you would have to do) defeat the purpose of using a "native" engine? :s Seems so to me, anyhow.

Comment: Javascript.Net (http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) has a fairly nice V8 Wrapper for .Net.

Comment: Yes, I know it. The whole point was to escape to complexity and limitation of mixed native/clr infrastructure in .net application server that already uses native JS engine (mozilla jseng) without performance degradation and even get some performance gain.